# the first time "that anyone can remember"

Tags: relative-clauses

I found this sentence today -

> For the first time **that anyone can remember** the gate of the park was open to the general public.

What does the clause **that anyone can remember** modify? What is the meaning of **that** here?

Can you please analyze this sentence, I have problem with **that anyone can remember** part? I want to learn the construction of this type.

Comment: *that anyone can remember* modifies *the first time* (by implication, it's possible *the gate of the park was open to the general public* on some previous occasion - but if so, no-one can remember that). I suspect the example is from a non-native speaker, because native speakers wouldn't normally talk about a *gate* being "open to the general public" (that would normally be said of the *park*, not the *gate*). That actual word "that" is effectively an optional "pronoun" referencing "the first time", which would often be deleted (as it is after "remember" here).

Comment: @FumbleFingers why not post that as an answer instead of a comment? There's not much more to say.

Comment: Are you talking about Arvind Kejiriwal's direct interaction with the public of Delhi which ultimately turned into chaos?

Comment: @Esoteric: It's not (yet?) clear to me why OP has difficulty parsing the highlighted text. Someone else (perhaps even a non-native speaker) may immediately recognise why it might appear "problematic", and thus be better equipped than me to clarify the issue. As you imply, I personally haven't got much more to say about it, because to me it's just "ordinary English". But I will say that my final point about a deleted "that" before "remember" was based on a hasty misreading of something more like *"**It was** the first time anyone can remember [**that**] the gate was open."*

Answer (score 2):

As FumbleFingers tells you, *that* here is a relative pronoun, equivalent to *which*. It heads a relative clause, in which it stands for the object of the verb *remember*; that relative clause modifies the noun phrase *the first time*.

The NP + relative clause

> the first time that anyone can remember

might thus be paraphrased as:

> No one can remember an earlier time when the gate was open; this is the first such time.